# Get memory location and space associated to process using processId

Tags: java, windows, wmic, taskmanager

I want to get the memory information(address and size) of a process in Ram using process id.
I tried WMIC and task manager they provide only the memory used by the process at current time. 
Could anyone please let me know how to get this information from windows OS.

Comment: How does this relate to Java? You might consider removing the java tag from your question.

Comment: Because the solution I get is to implement the in Java. If anyone knows the solution in Java then it helps a lot.

Comment: That makes sense. I would suggest that you add this to your question, as it will help getting more meaningful answers for your use case. I don't know the Windows API that gets the information you need, but you can always use the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) library to invoke it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

All programs in Windows load at the same address. 0x00400000 (that's 4 MB). I suggest you say what what you are trying to find out as your answer is always 4 MB.